Schwarzschild acceleration in exact form as a function of position and velocity vector?
Let us look at the most simple example of one large spherically symmetric mass and a small test-mass moving around it.
In the old non-Riemannian gravitional theory of Newton you can find the acceleration of the test-mass as a function of the central mass and the position of the test-mass, ignoring the way the test-mass is moving. This is simply:
$${d\bar{v}\over{dt}}=f(\bar{r},GM)=-{GM\over{r^3}}\bar{r}.$$
Question: Now under general relativity and this most simple spherically symmetric Schwarzschild conditions can you find an exact expression for the acceleration (in coordinate time or simulation time) as an expression of both the position vector and velocity vector that exactly recreates the Schwarzschild orbits exactly if you run it in a step by step numerical integration simulation and what does that expression look like? Is it theoretically impossible to find such an expression and if so why?
There are some common approximations such as the post-Newtonian expansion that does not really work well for stronger fields at least at the "1 PN" and the "3PN" levels. I found a peer reviewed and published paper from Rosswog/Tejeda from 2013 which contains an expression which is the best approximation I have seen.
(I asked basically this same question on physics stack exchange a year ago but did not receive any answers.)

Such questions have been answered at times of Euler already.
Choose coordinates, adapted to picturing symmetries.
Here the choice of Schwarzschild is an orthogonal, time independent, rotation invariant 4d-system.
Establish the variational equations for a system of optimal control - ie no external influence self guiding along free fall geodesics -  using the 4d-metrics with a positive sign for the time direction, defining the metric square of tangent vectors in terms of arc length s
$$\delta \int_a^b L(\dot x(s), x(s)) ds=0$$
with fixed end points $a,b$.
Choose the longest possible path by bord time $s$ (i.e dont waste fuel for acceleration manoeuvers, the coordinate times for start and goal are fixed).
Let the curve in 4d space-time $s\to (t(s),\ x(s))$ with metrics on tangent vectors at point $P$ in spherical coordinates
$$\dot P \ = \ \left(  \dot t \ e_t, \ \dot r\  e_r, \ \dot \theta \ e_\theta, \ \dot \phi \  e_\phi \right)$$
All dots refer to arc length, defined by integrating the tangent vectors along  curves with the square root of the metrics as $$L=\ \frac{1}{2} \  \dot x \ G \  \dot x$$
$$G \ = \ 
\left(\begin{array}{cccc} 
               1- \frac{2m}{r}&0&0&0
             \\0 & -  \frac{1}{1- \frac{2m}{r}}&0&0
             \\0&0&-r^2&0\\
             \\0&0&0& -r^2\sin^2 \theta
\end{array} \right)$$
leading to the Lagrangian equations of of motiom
$$\frac{d}{ds} \nabla_{\dot x} \ L - \nabla_x \ L \ = \ 0 $$
There are no great differences to the sperical Kepler system, the angular momentum 3-vector is conserved by rotational invariance, the orbit is plane, the altitude angle $\theta=\pi/2, \dot \theta =0 $ is a possible constant of motion and can be discarded.
$$\frac{d}{dt} r^2 \dot \theta - r^2 \dot \phi^2 \ 2 \sin \theta \ \cos \theta$$
The system is free, there are quadratic velocity terms with coordinate $r$-dependent coefficients only. In this case the Hamiltonian is the Lagrangian with the inverse metrics acting on the momentum variables $p=\nabla_{\dot x }L$
$$H = \left(1-\frac{2m}{r} \right) \ p_t^2 - \frac{1}{1-\frac{2m}{r} } \ p_r^2 - \frac{\mathit L^2}{r^2} $$
with the total conserved angular momentum  $$p_\phi  = \partial_{\dot \phi} \ L =-  r ^2 \dot \phi .$$
Since the Hamiltonian is independent of coordinate time $t$ and arc length $s$, there are two additional constants of motion
$$p_t = \partial_{\dot t} = E $$
the time component of the 4-momentum, and the the value of the Hamiltonian
$$\dot H= \partial_s H =0$$
Since $$H = \frac{1}{2}( E^2 - p^2)  =\frac{1}{2} \ M^2$$
similar to flat space, we can adopt Einsteins notion of invariant mass and set the conserved mass to $M=1$.
This is the central point of Einstein: All masses fall equally fast (wrt to proper time!).
$$\frac{1}{1\ - \ \frac{2m}{r}}\  E - \left( 1\ - \ \frac{2m}{r}\right)\  p_r^2 -\frac{p_\phi^2}{r^2} \ = \frac{1}{1\ - \ \frac{2m}{r}} (E - \dot r ^2 )  - \frac{p_\phi^2}{r^2}  \ = \ 1 $$
Once the radial solution is at hand, the angular variable is dertermined by
$$r(s) \dot \phi = \frac{p_\phi}{ r(s)} $$
The orbit equation - as in the Kepler case - is found by elimination of the arc lenght variable $s$ from the angular momentum equation in the mass equation
$$\begin{align}& r^2 \dot \phi  = \frac{p_\phi}{r ^2}\\
& \frac{\dot r}{\dot \phi} = \frac{dr}{d\phi}\\
&\dot r(s) = r'(\phi) \ \frac{p_\phi}{r ^4} 
\end{align}  $$
$$\frac{1}{1\ - \ \frac{2m}{r}} \left(E -\left(r'(\phi) \ \frac{p_\phi}{r ^4}\right)^2 \right)  - \frac{p_\phi^2}{r^2}  \ = \ 1  $$
As a point of orientation, Newtons equation of balance of centrifugal and centripetal force for circular orbits now fulfils a relativistic equation for a energy slightly smaller than 1 and radius large compared to Schwarzschild radius $2 m$
$$\begin{align}
&\frac{E}{1\ - \ \frac{2m}{r}}    - \frac{p_\phi^2}{r^2}  \ = \ 1\\
&E\left( 1\ + \ \frac{2m}{r}\right) - \frac{p_\phi^2}{r^2}  \ = \ 1
\end{align}$$

I was looking for an expression in the form of $${d\bar{v}\over{dt}}=f(\bar{r},GM,\bar{v})$$ such that the resulting orbits becomes identical to what the Schwarzschild solution prescribes.

Time $t$ is not a variable but a coordinate used by observers at infinity with some strange effects as freezing  amotion at the horizon.

Yes as I tried to state in the question I mean t = coordinate time or "simulation time" if you will. I want the final expression to recreate the expected perihelion shift and orbital velocity from the Schwarzschild solution as well as the orbiting object falling in to the Schwarzchild radius and stopping. Has this been done already or can you somehow prove that it is not possible?
